# Presenting the UIDocumentPickerViewController and dismissing it keeps the presented view controller in freeze

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

How can I present the UIDocumentPickerViewController and dismissing it keeps the presented view controller in freeze

Comment: may be your PDFBrowserViewController is still there that's why the blur view is there.
just paste PDFBrowserViewController viewDidLoad code on your button and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you open *UIDocumentPickerViewController* in *PDFBrowserViewController* so when you dismiss *UIDocumentPickerViewController* but *PDFBrowserViewController* was not dismissed.

**solution 1:** open *UIDocumentPickerViewController* directly in top viewcontroller without use of *PDFBrowserViewController*.

**solution 2:** after dismiss *UIDocumentPickerViewController* dismiss the parent controller in Delegate methods.

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject];
UIViewController *vc = [window rootViewController];
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
```